# Linux not detected by grub

Tags: grub2, sabayon

I have two partitions with Linux, `/dev/sda7 and /dev/sda8`

`/dev/sda7` had Deeproot Linux installed (based on Ubuntu), later I installed Sabayon in `/dev/sda8`. It reinstalled the grub.

The problem is that it is not detecting my Deeproot Linux and is not showing it in the grub menu.

`update-grub` is not being recognized by Sabayon..

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: if possible post your grub.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update-grub is actually a wrapper of `grub-mkconfig` (or grub2-mkconfig on some system).

You can run this command as root (backup /boot/grub/grub.cfg first, or run grub-mkconfig to preview it without redirecting output)
Before running the command mount the partition /dev/sda7

`grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Which essentially would do the same as update-grub on Ubuntu based distros.

Comment: Mounting the deepin partition and then running grub2-mkconfig solved the problem.
any idea why the mount was required?

Comment: @Stormvirux the program just scans for vmlinuz and other kernel files by names, and doesn't do the mounting stuff automatically