# How to boot an encrypted Debian, from an unencrypted Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, grub2, luks

I am trying to setup a full-encrypted Debian os, alongside my preinstalled unencrypted Ubuntu.

so far, I have(traditional BIOS) installed the Debian with the following scheme..

1. /boot as extended partition; format-ext4 (unencrypted)
2. LVM on LUKS:
   / partition -ext4 (encrypted),
   SWAP (encrypted)
3. grub2 of Debian, installed on /boot instead MBR, since Ubuntu's grub2 is my primary bootloader.
4. then from Ubuntu side, I mounted /boot & LVM partitions, then updated grub.

   but, my grub2 dont recognize Debian.

   What should I do next ??

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Yeah, mounting the partitions of another Linux distro and using the grub update tool won't do what you want. Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335247/two-linux-distributions-grub-does-not-detect-other-one/335384#335384

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Ok. I got it. but the problem here is I have 'legacy boot' & am not technically good with command line.
I only got 2 related links on the internet. None of them, are straightforward to fix the problem.
 so, It would be helpful if someone write a How-to at least, a workaround on the topic.

Comment: cryptsetup & lvm2 are installed.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It worked. thanks a lot. I made it up with dual-booting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried an alternative method with grub2.
 I made a mistake when mounting the logical root partition. Since, I am not good with cli, so I wanted not to mess with grub2 config file. However, grub2 can handle LVM2 & LUKS partitions efficiently. look here (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#Extended_features).

So,here what I tried alternatively

1. step1, mounted the /boot partition.
2. step2, `$ sudo modprobe dm-crypt | grep dm-crypt`
3. step3, unlock the luks-encrypted partition with 'cryptsetup' command.
4. step4, run `$ sudo pvscan | vgscan | lvsacan`
5. step5, activate the volume-group
6. step6, mount the logical root volume. No need to mount the logical swap.
7. step7, `sudo update-grub`

Done!

Grub2 will autodetect the installed OS  & list it on grub menu.

Comment: life saver for who cannot install a bootable nvme.m2 debian, and need to boot it from other disk.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's what you can do.

**Warning**: this procedure will require heavy use of the command line and for the most part will require root access:

1. Boot Ubuntu.
2. Open `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` with a text editor.
3. Append the following to the file:

ignore this line (it's here to address formatting issues)

```
menuentry 'Debian' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'debian-0aca58bc-8fdb-4a07-aa2f-56406bcf19b7' {
   set root='hd0,msdos4'
   configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
}
```

4. Change the part that says `hd0,msdos4` to reflect your Debian's `/boot` partition. In this example, hd0 is the first disk and msdos4 is the 4th partition; This means disks begin at 0 and partitions begin at 1.
5. Save the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file.
6. Check to see if you have the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. If not that means you need to mount your `/boot` filesystem by running `mount /boot`.
7. Make a backup copy of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
8. Run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
9. Cross your fingers and reboot.

If all goes well you'll have a *Debian* entry in your Ubuntu GRUB menu. When you select that entry your screen will refresh and display your Debian GRUB menu, from which you can boot Debian.